# Stop exiting Eclipse with Play 2.3.X

Tags: eclipse, lombok, playframework-2.3

If I `run` my application (Play 2.3.2) while Eclipse is running I always have strange compilation errors, no class def found errors, class not found errors, etc...

If I exit Eclipse and run my application, everything is working fine. But sometimes it's also working fine while Eclipse is running.

Am I the only one to experience that ? What is the cause ?

I suspect something in Eclipse changes my source files but I can't find what.
Maybe Lombok ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have similar problems. Typesafe responded with a solution which I am currently trying out.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/4RnbqEk-muM

Brief summary of the answer by @jroper :

> Eclipse doesn't know
>   how to keep its dirty hands off the same build directory that Play is
>   using to compile your app - if you have both Play, and the IDE, trying
>   to compile the same code at the same time, what do you think will
>   happen?  You will see random errors.  You should configure Eclipse not
>   to automatically build your app, or configure it to have different
>   output directories.

Answer (score 0):

The Play Framework compiles everything to the directory target/scala-2.11/classes. When changing some of these classes, especially any views, causes Activator to auto compile the classes creating new class files. Hitting refresh on the project in Eclipse will update the project and class files in the classes directory causing a rebuild. This should make your compilation errors go away. If you still have issues, take a look at your .classpath file and the Eclipse build path settings.

Comment: The errors occur in Play console not in Eclipse. When they occur, I can't run my tests.
I think that Eclipse tries to modify files while activator is compiling. Activator seems to be lost.